# Basic ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I decided to write a simple page using ReactJS, but I'm new to it. The code snippet below doesn't work for an unknown reason (at least for me). What's wrong wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <script src="bower_components/react/react.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/react/react-dom.min.js"></script>
   <script src=bower_components/babel/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="my-div"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
   var Message = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
          return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      }
   });
   ReactDOM.render(<Message/>, document.getElementById('my-div'));
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?  Are you running a local server?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it via tomcat. And all I can see is a blank page.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console / developer tools? Seems to work fine in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9s41x11/

Comment: Well, it seems to me that it fails lo load the libraries.
ERROR: GET http://localhost:8080/bower_components/babel/browser.min.js%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry for posting a silly question. I made no mistakes in my code except for one.

```
     src=bower_components/babel/browser.min.js"
```

I missed a quote symbol. It should be:

```
     src="bower_components/babel/browser.min.js"
```

Anyways, thank you for your attempts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can imagine is wrong with this code - is wrong path to scripts. Check console for problems with such problem.

Try to use maybe a CDN react instead of these from bower and tell what result is. Also, if you don't want to try CDN maybe try to add "/" before bower_components, that is

```
../bower_components/react
/bower_components/react
```

(wild guess)

[Dom](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js)

[React](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js)